# Mongo: How to use the results of a search, in another search?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have currently a request doing some searching operations ($match, $sort, $group, then another $match).
Sample response:

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "actor": "fcc0895c-ba04-3078-92b7-3328a283a93a",
        "level": 30
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "actor": "58b84177-5354-3a69-938f-449991e75e49",
        "level": 30
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "actor": "d8bcb9d8-e8cb-3796-8d78-fca4d63054fc",
        "level": 30
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "actor": "8a6287ea-7498-8a21-0174-9ac4c64c23e1",
        "level": 30
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "actor": "af266e72-4455-39b4-a64c-586055358962",
        "level": 30
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "actor": "8a62879f-6aac-dea3-016a-b53d9bd96365",
        "level": 30
    }
}
```

]

I have to complete my query in order to do another research where I would be able to filter on this "actor" attribute.

I tried the "$lookup" key but not sure it is the good way... How could I achieve that please? :)

Comment: Do you mind sharing what "another research" means by sharing your current code and expected output? [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) will be a great tool

Comment: Hello,
Of course I can :): https://mongoplayground.net/p/DKqbe0CAsX1
The query I set is what I got currently: a list of person who have a goal level, for a specific skill, of 30.
What I would like now is to get the current level of the person, who have this goal level (2nd document).

In psql, it would be something like a IN. Maybe I can achieve that using $lookup with the pipeline attribute?

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I need... I am going to look in detail, thanks a lot Ray !

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may just need one more self lookup.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "skill-id": "03194859-a8d4-4eda-89e3-09beab3cf336"
        },
        {
          "event-type": "evaluated"
        },
        {
          "assessment-type": "TARGET"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "actor": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "actor": "$actor",
        "target": "$statement-level"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id.target": 30
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        actor: "$_id.actor"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$actor",
                    "$$actor"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$skill-id",
                    "03194859-a8d4-4eda-89e3-09beab3cf336"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$assessment-type",
                    "CURRENT"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "currentLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$currentLookup",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      currentSkillLevel: "$currentLookup.statement-level"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yFLHFqHFBbk) for your reference.

Please note that it uses [uncorrelated subqueries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) which is only available for MongoDB 3.6+